# How is conditional probability being used here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Because of conditional probability: $P(A\mid B)=P(A,B)/P(B)$, $$P(C(t)\in dt\mid x(T^+_{i-1}),x(T^-_{i}))=\dfrac{P(C(t)\in dt,x(T^-_{i})\in dx\mid x(T^+_{i-1}))}{P(x(T^-_{i})\in dx\mid x(T^+_{i-1}))},$$ Could someone tell me why the above \begin{align}=\dfrac{P(C(t)\in dt\mid x(T^+_{i-1}))\times P(x(T^-_{i})\in dx\mid C(t),x(T^+_{i-1}))}{P(x(T^-_{i})\in dx|\;x(T^+_{i-1}))}\\
=\dfrac{P(C(t)\in dt\mid x(T^+_{i-1}))\times P(x(T^-_{i})\in dx\mid x(t)=\log(H))}{P(x(T^-_{i})\in dx\mid x(T^+_{i-1}))},
\end{align}
$C(t)$ is the event: process $x$ crosses barrier $\log(H)$ for the first time in $[t,t+dt]$.

I think the problem is mainly about using properties of conditional expectation. You can find the problem on page 47 of [this article](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~amir/barrier.pdf)

Comment: I changed |\; to \mid.  That automatically provides proper spacing on both the left and the right.

Comment: The notations are confusing. If $C(t)$  is the event of crossing the barrier for $dt$ why your wrote $C(t)\in dt$. $C(t)$ is not measurared in time units or redefine your event, like so:$C(t)$  is the random variable whic is the first time $x$ crosses the barrier. So the event is $C(t) \in dt$.  And then we can calculate the prob of such event. Sorry for the tiresomeness.

Comment: As @AlexanderVigodner explained, this question needs some serious rewriting.

Comment: @Did, This is how it is in the article. I have put a link to the problem.